# Making pagination API calls simulaneously using Spring Webclient

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have to make paginated API calls, using Webclient and combine all the result at last.
For ex : Person latest 1000 transaction details.
In one call, i am gonna get max 100 Objects in json response (List).
I can only get maximum 1000 records for this Person.

In pseudo code - java, it could look something like this

```
    int Total = 1000;
    int maxEachCall = 100;
    int noOfCalls = maxTotal/maxEachCall;
    int startIndex = 0;

    List<MyDto> mailList = new ArrayList();

    for(int i =startIndex; i<noOfCalls ;i+100){
        List<MyDto> list =  webClient.get().uri(baseUri+"?startIndex"+startIndex)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(MyDto.class)                            
                        .retry(3)
                        .block();
        mainList.addAll(list);
        if(startIndex>900 || list.size()<100){
            break;
        }
    }
```

How can i write the same thing in reactive way WITHOUT blocking in spring mvc ?

Something like this??? I dont know. Help me

```
    int Total = 1000;
    int maxEachCall = 100;
    int noOfCalls = maxTotal/maxEachCall;
      int startIndex = 0;
    Flux.range(1,noOfCalls)
        .flatMap(
            // tried to call api using startIndex but can't use startIndex here or manipulate it
        )
        .doOnError(e->LOGGER.info("Exception occured ",e))
        .blockLast(); ???
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to:

```
Flux.range(0, 10)
        .map(start -> start * 100)
        .flatMap(
                start -> webClient.get()
                        .uri(baseUri + "?startIndex=" + start)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(MyDtoCollection.class)
                        .map(c -> splitCollectionIntoIndividualMyDto(c)) //or something to that effect, since you'll get 100 `MyDto` at a time and presumably need to split them.
        )
        .collectList();
```

...which will provide you with a `Mono<List<MyDto>>` containing all your paginated results. If your stack is fully reactive you would then continue to use that `Mono` in the reactive chain elsewhere. If not (yet) fully reactive, and you're just using reactor for this bit, you can then choose to `block()` at the most sensible location.

Comment: How to break the pipeline on certain condition and assemble the result till that point? I added one more condition in if.

Comment: @AsifAnsari A `filter()` call may be what you're after, after the `flatMap()` call.

Comment: filter() will parse all the emitted values, right? If i want to stop at 5, it will still filter 6 to 10 unnecessary. I mean it won't break out, right?

Comment: @AsifAnsari Yup, it will. It sounds like you want to get one chunk, process it, then decide if you want to get the next chunk? That won't work in this scenario, since all of those web requests are effectively made simultaneously. You can do that if you process them one at a time, but that will obviously take longer (and there's then not a great deal of advantage in using reactor at all.)